# GlassFish won't deploy webService

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-5

I'm using the new Glassfish 5 version, and trying to deploy a simple web application which contains a web service.

When trying to deploy the '.war' file I get an exception and it is not being deployed.
When using Glassfish 4 there were no problems deploying it.
(I have to use glassfish 5 because of security reasons).
This Is the Exception I get inside the server.log file:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:185)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:254)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:232)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:276)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:377)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:699)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:691)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeFinalWsdlUrl(WebServiceEndpoint.java:754)
at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.doWebServicesDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:625)
at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:177)
... 65 more]]`
```

What could be the problem? 
Do I need to add or change my web service implementation? 
Is there something to change inside glassfish properties ?

This is My WebService code: (It is a very simple web-service, just for testing the deployment).

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "Test")
public class Test {

    public Test() {
    }


    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

Please Help!

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: Silly question: I see you're using SOAP (javax.jws). Does it help to switch to REST (javax.ws.rs)?